# How to set CR3 register while in long mode (64 bit)

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-64, page-tables

I am working on my operating systems project. Starter code already jumps to long mode and sets up temporary page tables. I have now setup and filled my own pagetables and finished mapping memory the way I need. Now I need to set physical address of PML4T in CR3 register.

```
238 void setcr3(void * addr){
239 uint64_t temp=(uint64_t)addr;
240
241   __asm__ ("movq %0, %%cr3;"::"b"(temp));
242 }
```

This crashes while executing that instruction. GDB step by step attached

```
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) b setcr3
Breakpoint 1 at 0xffffffff80201205: file sys/paging.c, line 238.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, setcr3 (addr=0x221000) at sys/paging.c:238
238     void setcr3(void * addr){
(gdb) si
241       __asm__ ("movq %0, %%cr3;"::"b"(temp));
(gdb) si
0xffffffff80201209      241       __asm__ ("movq %0, %%cr3;"::"b"(temp));
(gdb) si
242     }
(gdb) si
Remote connection closed
(gdb)
244 #define write_cr3(x) \
245 __asm__ __volatile__("movl %0,%%cr3": :"r" (x))


Error while compiling

sys/paging.c: Assembler messages:
sys/paging.c:271: Error: unsupported instruction `mov'
```

Edit:

```
printf("address in cr3 %x\n", (uint64_t)pml4t - 0xffffffff80200000 + physbase);
setcr3( (void *) ( (uint64_t)pml4t - 0xffffffff80200000 + physbase) );


line 1 prints:
address in cr3 221000
```

Comment: You forgot to specify your target architecture

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to show the actual instruction at the fault. I assume it is `movq %rbx, %cr3`. Furthermore, you also forgot to show the value of `%rbx` (or whatever the source register is).

That said, the instruction set reference lists these two applicable conditions for a fault:

- If the current privilege level is not 0.
- If an attempt is made to write a 1 to any reserved bit in CR3.

Comment: value im writing into the register is 0x221000

Comment: That looks harmless according to the conditions listed. Double check it isn't actually the changed paging table prohibiting fetching the next instruction. Might also be a problem with your debugging environment. I was able to write `0x221000` to `cr3`. Unless you can post complete runnable code, I don't think I can help much more.

Answer (score 0):

> **asm** ("movq %0, %%cr3;"::"b"(temp));

In place of "b", I recommend using "r" so that compiler takes care of which register to be used to move the value and restores it after executing the instruction.

> **asm** **volatile**("movl %0,%%cr3": :"r" (x));

Use movq instead of movl.

> setcr3( (void *) ( (uint64_t)pml4t - 0xffffffff80200000 + physbase) );

If the page tables are being set for the first time in the kernel, you need to only deduct 0xffffffff80200000 from the virtual address of pml4t in order to pass physical address to the cr3 register. There is no need to add physbase. This is because, you might be taking the first available address in memory after loading the kernel's elf sections.

Finally, it is better to add volatile before the asm block so that the compiler does not optimize the instruction. Also, to avoid typecasting, use the below line directly instead of macro and see what happens.

> **asm** **volatile**("movq %[cr3_var], %%cr3;"::[cr3_var]"r"((uint64_t)pml4t));